# One controller with action inside action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to use a Controller with an Action after two slashes, as if it were an action within an action.

Example: `.../Administration/Institution/Register/Id`

I was using the solution: `.../Administration/InstitutionRegister/Id`

But I find an ugly solution, if I could use as in the first example would be better.

It is possible?
Thank you!

Comment: Look up attribute based routing.

Comment: Do you have a more specific term? I have tried to search, but nothing that refers to it exactly.

Comment: "attribute based routing" takes you to everything you need!

Comment: @FelipeSalazar Have you managed to sort your problem out using attribute routing ?

Comment: @Skrface I'm trying to do it this way:
        [Route("Administration/Institution/Register")]
        public ActionResult RegisterInstitution(int id) {
            return View();
        }

Comment: @FelipeSalazar And does it suits your needs ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing) in order to create a specific URL for an action :

```
[Route("Administration/Institution/Register")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks, it helps.